# Beam - Filter out Records from Bigquery

Tags: python-3.x, apache-beam, dataflow

I am new to Apache Beam, and I trying to do three tasks

1. Read Top 30 Items from the table
2. Read Top 30 Stores from the table
3. select required columns from the bigquery and apply Filter on the columns **Items** and **Stores**.

I have this below code, to execute the pipeline

```
with beam.Pipeline(options=pipeline_args) as p:
        #read the dataset from bigquery
        query_top_30_items = (
            p 
            | 'GetTopItemNumbers' >> beam.io.ReadFromBigQuery(
                query="""SELECT item_number, COUNT(item_number) AS freq_count FROM 
                [bigquery-public-data.iowa_liquor_sales.sales] GROUP BY item_number 
                ORDER BY freq_count DESC
                LIMIT 30"""
            )
            | 'ReadItemNumbers' >> beam.Map(lambda elem: elem['item_number'])
            | 'ItemNumberAsList' >> beam.combiners.ToList()
        )


        query_top_30_stores = (
            p
            |
            'GetTopStores' >> beam.io.ReadFromBigQuery(
                query = """SELECT store_number, COUNT(store_number) AS store_count
                 FROM [bigquery-public-data.iowa_liquor_sales.sales] GROUP BY
                 store_number ORDER BY store_count DESC LIMIT 30"""
            )
            | 'ReadStoreValues' >> beam.Map(lambda elem:elem['store_number'])
            | 'StoreValuesAsList' >> beam.combiners.ToList()
        )

        query_whole_table = (
            (query_top_30_items, query_top_30_stores)
            |'ReadTable' >> beam.io.ReadFromBigQuery(
                query="""SELECT item_number, store_number, bottles_sold,
                    state_bottle_retail  FROM [bigquery-public-data.iowa_liquor_sales.sales]""")
            | 'FilterByItems' >> beam.Filter(lambda row:row['item_number'] in query_top_30_items)
            | 'FilterByStore' >> beam.Filter(lambda row:row['store_number'] in query_top_30_stores)
        )
```

I have attached Traceback for reference. How Can I solve this error?

> temp_location = pcoll.pipeline.options.view_as( Traceback (most
> recent call last):   File "run.py", line 113, in 
> run()   File "run.py", line 100, in run
> | 'FilterByStore' >> beam.Filter(lambda row:row['store_number'] in query_top_30_stores)   File
> "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/apache_beam/transforms/ptransform.py", line 1058, in **ror**
> return self.transform.**ror**(pvalueish, self.label)   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/apache_beam/transforms/ptransform.py", line 573, in **ror**
> result = p.apply(self, pvalueish, label)   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/apache_beam/pipeline.py",
> line 646, in apply
> return self.apply(transform, pvalueish)   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/apache_beam/pipeline.py",
> line 689, in apply
> pvalueish_result = self.runner.apply(transform, pvalueish, self._options)   File
> "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/apache_beam/runners/runner.py",
> line 188, in apply
> return m(transform, input, options)   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/apache_beam/runners/runner.py",
> line 218, in apply_PTransform
> return transform.expand(input)   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/apache_beam/io/gcp/bigquery.py",
> line 1881, in expand
> temp_location = pcoll.pipeline.options.view_as( AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'pipeline'

Since I am new to Beam, the code is not that optimized. Please let me know If I can optimize this code further.

Thanks for your time and Help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`beam.io.ReadFromBigQuery` must be at the root of your pipeline, and takes the pipeline object (not a `PCollection` or tuple of `PCollection`s) as input. Hence the error.

As the other answer mentions, you could try to write the whole thing as a single BigQuery query. Otherwise, you could do the filtering after the read using [side inputs](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/programming-guide/#side-inputs), e.g.

```
with beam.Pipeline(options=pipeline_args) as p:
    #read the dataset from bigquery
    query_top_30_items = ...

    query_top_30_stores = ...

    sales = p |'ReadTable' >> beam.io.ReadFromBigQuery(
        query="""SELECT item_number, store_number, bottles_sold,
    state_bottle_retail  FROM [bigquery-public-data.iowa_liquor_sales.sales]""")

    filtered = (
        sales
        | 'FilterByItems' >> beam.Filter(
            lambda row, items_side_input: row['item_number'] in items_side_input,
            items_side_input=beam.pvalue.AsList(query_top_30_items))
        | 'FilterByStore' >> beam.Filter(
            lambda row, stores_side_input: row['store_number'] in stores_side_input,
            stores_side_input=beam.pvalue.AsList(query_top_30_stores))
    )
```

Comment: Hi @robertwb, once I filter the records, I couldn't write the rows as .csv files (or) any other files?

Comment: Hey, I have figured out the error, why it is not writing any content on File. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Apply Filter condition over a function will not work in a pipeline. You have 2 option for the same:-

1. Apply Filter condition within pipeline.
2. Apply filter condition over BQ-SQL.

Filter condition over Function will be ambiguous for Function what to return to calling function. Hence modify you code to apply filter conditions to either of 2 place highlighted above.

Comment: Can I do some sort like this   ``` query_whole_table = (
            (query_top_30_items, query_top_30_stores)
            |'ReadTable' >> beam.io.ReadFromBigQuery(
                query="""SELECT item_number, store_number, bottles_sold,
                    state_bottle_retail  FROM [bigquery-public-data.iowa_liquor_sales.sales]""")
            | 'FilterByItems' >> beam.Filter(lambda row:row['item_number'] in query_top_30_items)
            | 'FilterByStore' >> beam.Filter(lambda row:row['store_number'] in query_top_30_stores)
        )``` in the pipeline?

Comment: I have modified the code in the question. Can you take a look?

Comment: I am still dough full that it will work because data from 2 different PCollection in array format but still you can check. Moreover, if you have complete data from BiqQuery, why don't you do joining and filtering on BQ and read final data in your pipeline, eventually Cost wise it will remain same as you are already reading data from BQ.

Comment: I have tried to do Joining and Filtering on BQ itself, but  I need to filter the records based on top 30 items and store numbers, putting those in SQL query placeholder itself a challenging one. I'll try this method too. Currently, the pipeline take 12 mins to complete. But, I guess, if we put that in BQ itself, then the execution should be completed for a short time

Comment: Yes, you are correct, if u move code to BQ it will be much quicker. Moreover on filtering part, try to create different sub-Queries or View for top 30 items and then join accordingly to get required data as output.

Comment: Hey, If I want to apply the partition on above filtered data and do compute "average_past_15days_sales" using window function what is the reliable method? Should I write the filtered results in temporary BQ table, partition by (store, item_number) and sort by Date in BQ itself, and Read the data in beam, and apply windowing function? (or) Simply use DataFrame API?

Comment: It will be better idea to create partitioned intermediate table based on data available, as it will reduce data processing volume and cost. Generally its a good idea to have partition on date and clustering on string field and then apply filter on query and then read data on apache beam. 'Windowing' on beam will not be applied while reading data from BQ table. It can be applicable if you are reading data from Pub/Sub.